# Rotate sin cos plot by +90 degrees

Tags: java, rotation, trigonometry

I am writing a simple java program to achieve the following output ie plot sin and cos but rotate the output 90 degrees in intervals (x 0 to 360 in steps of 10) . sin plotted with * and cos plotted with o.

```
x=  0      *      o
x= 10       *     o
x= 20        *   o
x= 30         *  o
x= 40          *o
x= 50          o*
x= 60         o  *
x= 70        o   *
x= 80       o     *
x= 90      o      *
x= 100     o       *
x= 110    o       *
x= 120   o        *
x= 130  o        *
x= 140  o        *
x= 150 o        *
x= 160 o       *
x= 170 o      *
x= 180 o     *
x= 190 o    * 
x= 200 o   * 
x= 210 o  *
x= 220 o*
x= 230  *o 
x= 240 *  o
x= 250 *   o 
x= 260 *    o
x= 270 *     o
x= 280 *      o
x= 290 *       o
x= 300 *        o
x= 310  *        o
x= 320  *        o
x= 330   *        o
x= 340    *       o
x= 350     *       o
x= 360      *      o
```

This is my code

```
class SinCos {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numx = 360;
        double numy = 25.0;

    for (double y = 1 ; y >= -1 ; y-=1/numy) {
        double nexty = y-(1/numy);

        for (double x = 0; x <= numx; x+=10) {

            double siny = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
            double cosy = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));

            if (siny >= nexty && siny <= y)
                System.out.print('*');
            else
                System.out.print(' ');

            if (cosy >= nexty && cosy <= y)
                System.out.print('o');
            else
                System.out.print(' ');
        }
      System.out.println();
     }
    }
}
```

How do I rotate the output and print the values of x as the example.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve it.
Run with java SinCos a1 a2 platos
i.e java SinCos 0 360 25

```
class SinCos {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a1, a2, w, platos;

    a1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    w = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (!(a1 <= a2)) {
        System.out.println("a1 must be <= a2");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    platos = (w / 2) + 1;

    System.out.println();
    for (int x = a1; x <= a2; x += 10) {

        int sinValue = (int) Math.round(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)) * platos);
        int cosValue = (int) Math.round(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x)) * platos);

        System.out.printf("x= %4s", x + " ");

        for (int j = -platos; j <= platos; j++) {

            if (j == sinValue)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(' ');

            if (j == cosValue) {

                System.out.print("o");
            } else
                System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```